# Windows easy-to-install Asciidoc editor

Tags: windows, gratis, text-editor

[Asciidoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AsciiDoc) is a text-based document format.

I tried the [AsciiDoctor editor](http://asciidoctor.org) , but it requires installing Ruby and typing `gem install asciidoctor`, which scares away potential writers, especially the ones who use Windows.

Is there an extremely-easily installable Asciidoc editor for Windows?

Requirements:

- Installable (or portable) via .msi or .exe
- Zero configuration
- Either WYSIWYG or code+preview is OK
- Free

Comment: You're correct in that installation of AsciiDoc is way too complicated for writers to use. Your post of nearly 8 years ago shows that there has been no attempt to improve this. I'm not new to programming doing embedded systems firmware and software for 20 years. I spent a day trying to install and use AsciiDoc. The dependencies required and left to the user are too complicated for people not in the Ruby side of the software field. I thought the Visual Studio Code app was going to work best, but I ended up with a bunch of Ruby errors when trying to install AsciiDoc Preview. I think LaTex is sim

Answer (score 7):

Hands down, the best for me is for now AsciidocFX : http://asciidocfx.com/

One package to install gives you an asciidoc editor with live preview, a toolbar with selected snippets, and a complete toolchain to produce the html, ebook or pdf files.

Answer (score 2):

Atom Editor for Windows now has an easy installer. https://atom.io/

I think Atom Editor is the best AsciiDoc editor for Windows.

Add these two packages:

**language-asciidoc** for Syntax highlighting for AsciiDoc
https://atom.io/packages/language-asciidoc
If you save your files with the .adoc extention, this package will automatically highlight. If you prefer .txt extention, you can click "plain text" in lower-right-hand status bar and select AsciiDoc from the drop-down to get highlighting in a .txt file.

**asciidoc-preview**
To show an HTML preview for the AsciiDoc content

Usage: Packages > AsciiDoc > Toggle Preview (Shift-Ctrl-A)

I also use the View > Toggle Soft Wrap to keep the text from being too wide

Comment: Atom is no longer supported :/

Answer (score 1):

**SynWrite** is almost it: it's not shipped with Asciidoc lexer, of course (because Asciidoc format is not popular), but it's with lexer library dialog, in which you can copy Markdown lexer to "Asciidoc", and then edit this lexer copy for Asciidoc format.

Comment: What do you mean "fix copy for Asciidoc"? Is there a button to easily convert from Markdown to Asciidoctor format?

Comment: Changed text. Copy MD lexer to Asciidoc, and edit new one with lexer dialog, in app.

Answer (score 1):

If install [chocalatey](https://chocolatey.org/) is not a problem for you, you can try **Atom** editor and the asciidoc-preview extension.

https://atom.io/packages/asciidoc-preview

There is also **Brackets** editor with also a asciidoc-preview.

https://github.com/asciidoctor/brackets-asciidoc-preview/

Comment: That's unfortunately too technical for my writers. (see first requirement)

Comment: Atom recently switched from chocolatey to conventional installation - you can download windows installer from [atom webpage](http://atom.io).
You can also use [asciidoctor Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/asciidoctorjs-live-previe/iaalpfgpbocpdfblpnhhgllgbdbchmia) for preview and any text editor for writing.